# Is there a way to directly open Chrome's “dedicated devtools for node”?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, debugger

I use Firefox for my daily browsing; so the process of getting a Node inspector running is somewhat annoying:

1. Launch Chrome.
2. Manually visit `chrome://inspect`, because it refuses to set a builtin page as the ‘homepage’.
3. Click “Open dedicated DevTools for Node.”
4. Close the original window after the Node devtools opens.

This dedicated tools window is the only Chrome window I ever use. Is there any way to launch it from the command-line, or when Chrome opens?

Answer (score 3):

Have Chrome's homepage set to this:
`chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/node_app.html`

When Chrome opens, the dedicated node Devtools will automatically be opened, but not as a pop-up.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work — the manually-opened copy of the DevTools interface doesn't continuously and automatically detect and connect to Node debuggers, the way the built-in method does. )=

Comment: Have you tried using the connections tab? It might be a viable workaround.

Comment: and i make chrome shortcut for that

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Ultrasonic54321's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1362270/167207). The prefix was changed from chrome-devtools to devtools only. See https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/224

But playing around a bit with it, it does behave differently than the one open manually through the inspector.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

See the release note: https://github.com/sandipchitale/node-debugger/releases/tag/v0.1

It uses java.awt.Robot to launch Chrome and drive to the dedicated devtools for node page.

- Extract the .zip
- Run the command
- Linux/Mac:

  ```
  cd launch-node-debugger
  bin/launch-node-debugger
  ```
- Windows:

  ```
  cd launch-node-debugger
  bin\launch-node-debugger.bat
  ```

You may add the bin folder to PATH environment variable.

You can add it as a pre script in package.json like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "launch-node-debugger",
    "start": "node --inspect-brk index.js"
  },
}
```